# crontab job chech and restarts if stops

Tags: centos, cron

I have added some script to do on crontab, but how to check if its running, and if script or cron job stops to restart it automatically.

0 2 * * * bash /tcpdump_getdata.sh

Can you just direct me?

Answer (score 1):

> ... how to check if its running ...

cron is a *Scheduler*, not a *Monitor*.

All cron does is to launch processes whenever you tell it to.

It has no capability to tell whether any process is *already* running; that's not its job.  If you want "something" running *all* the time, then it should be set up as a Service (and the Service-controlling infrastructure *does* have ways to monitor if your Service process disappears).

Note that cron itself runs as a Service and so will be automatically restarted if *it* disappears.

If you want to limit your process so that it can only have one instance running at any time, then you have to code that process to handle that.